# Creating a Log File with DomPDF

Tags: php, logging, font-awesome, dompdf

I'm having a problem getting font-awesome to work inside of a DomPDF document on my webserver. However, the same HTML does work when using eclecticgeek.com's DomPDF debug helper.  Therefore, I know there is not problem with the HTML. Here's a link to the working code:

http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php?identifier=d0c3b30ed7fd65fabb5c64dda47decc5

I am trying to populate DomPDF's log file on my local webserver to help isolate the issue, but no file is generating for me. Here's my full code, I am trying to set the log file via DomPDF's options, but am not sure I am doing it right.

```
<?php

require_once "sites/all/libraries/dompdf/autoload.inc.php";
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$HTML = <<<HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Macondo" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
  .fa {
    display: inline;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span> Font awesome doesn't work on my webserver</p>
   <p style='font-family: "FontAwesome"'> &#xf2b9; </p> <span> this also does not work </span>
  <p style='font-family: "Macondo", cursive;'> This font works</p>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$dompdf = new \Dompdf\Dompdf(array(
    'tempDir' => 'sites/test.com/modules/CCPDF/',
    'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
    'isPhpEnabled' => true,
    'isJavascriptEnabled' => true,
    'pdfBackend' => "CPDF",
    'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true,
    'logOutputFile' => 'sites/test.com/modules/CCPDF/test.log',
    'DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED' => true
));
$dompdf->load_html($HTML);
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();

 ?>
```

Can anybody provide an example of how to properly set the DomPDF log file?

Comment: Side note, If you're trying to use font-awesome with domPDF version 0.8, it seems there is an issue that isnt allowing this to work. You're better off using version 0.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a snippet of the PHP I use when I'm debugging locally.

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_log', 'output/tester.err.log');
ini_set('log_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$dompdf_options = array(
    'chroot' => '/',
    'logOutputFile' => __DIR__ . '/dompdf.log.html',
    'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true,
    'debugPng' => false,
    'debugKeepTemp' => false,
    'debugCss' => false,
    'debugLayout' => false,
    'debugLayoutLines' => false,
    'debugLayoutBlocks' => false,
    'debugLayoutInline' => false,
    'debugLayoutPaddingBox' => false
);

$_dompdf_show_warnings = true;
$_dompdf_debug = false;
$_DOMPDF_DEBUG_TYPES = [
   'page-break' => false
];

$dompdf = new Dompdf\Dompdf($dompdf_options);
echo 'Running with ' , $dompdf->version , "\n";
$_dompdf_warnings = array();
echo 'Rendering '. $test_file . "\n";
$dompdf->load_html_file($test_file);
$dompdf->render();
file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/' . basename($test_file) . (strtolower($dompdf_options['pdfBackend']) === 'gd' ? '.png' : '.pdf'), $dompdf->output(array('compress'=>0)));
```

You can play around with the debug settings to get different types of debug information.

Comment: Thanks Brian, this should help!